# Is it possible to export ANTLR4 railroad diagrams as png? If so, how?

Tags: java, grammar, antlr4, antlrworks2

I want to export ANTLR4 rules in the railroad format.

Please notice that this format is not the same as generated by command line option "-atn".

The railroad format is generated by antlrworks, but I'd like to generate this programatically.

I am looking for something like http://clapham.sourceforge.net/

clapham generates what I want from BNF. Is there any tool to convert from antlr4 to BNF? (question probably related to [Generate BNF diagrams from an antlr grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436796/generate-bnf-diagrams-from-an-antlr-grammar), but notice I am not asking the same thing here. Converting to BNF is just a workaround, what I want is to generate the railroad diagram directly from ANTLR grammar)

Following the answer for [Generate BNF diagrams from an antlr grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436796/generate-bnf-diagrams-from-an-antlr-grammar) worked for me

Just get your ANTLR grammar, send to https://www.bottlecaps.de/convert/ and then to https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui

ANTLR4 expressions such as "WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;" could not be processed so I've changed to the traditional form "WS       ::= ( #x9 | #xD | #xA )*"

Clapham could not work with the BNF grammar generated by https://www.bottlecaps.de/convert/ unfortunately.

This is a way to get the diagram, but **this is not programatically**. **I wish I had some JAR I could just add to generate on the fly.**

Answer (score 3):

Here's a library [I wrote] that you can execute from the command line, or embed into your own code, to generate PNG or SVG railroad diagrams from ANTLR 4 grammar rules:

https://github.com/bkiers/rrd-antlr4

Answer (score 0):

Checkout ANTLR 4 IDE: https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide

Here is a Java.g4 to HTML example: http://jknack.github.io/antlr4ide/Java/Javav4.g4.html

You will find images under the http://jknack.github.io/antlr4ide/Java/images directory.

The last update to this tool was in December 2016.

Comment: sounds impressive. can i generate the diagram from the command line?

Comment: d-oh! I missed that from you question and no, you can't do it from command line :(

Comment: er - where in antlr4ide can I generate the diagram?